# how do you deal with multiple drop down forms that are grayed out with scrapy FormRequest

Tags: python, post, compiler-errors, web-scraping, scrapy

So I'm trying to scrap some car info off of Gasbuddy.com, but I'm having some trouble with the scrapy code.

here is what I have so far, let me know what I'm doing wrong:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class gasBuddy(BaseSpider):
name = "gasBuddy"
allowed_domains = ["http://www.gasbuddy.com"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.gasbuddy.com/Trip_Calculator.aspx",
]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    #for years in hxs.select('//select[@id="ddlYear"]/option/text()'):
        #print years
    FormRequest(url="http://www.gasbuddy.com/Trip_Calculator.aspx",
                formdata={'Year': '%s'%("2011")},
                callback=self.make('2011'))


def make (years, self, response):
    #this is where we loop through all of the car makes and send the response to modle
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    for makes in hxs.select('//select[@id="ddlMake"]/option/text()').extract()
        FormRequest(url="http://www.gasbuddy.com/Trip_Calculator.aspx",
                formdata={'Year': '%s', 'Make': '%s'%(years, makes)},
                callback=self.model(years, makes))


def model (years, makes, self, response):
    #this is where we loop through all of the car modles and get all of the data assoceated with it.
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    for models in hxs.select('//select[@id="ddlModel"]/option/text()')
        FormRequest(url="http://www.gasbuddy.com/Trip_Calculator.aspx",
                formdata={'Year': '%s', 'Make': '%s', 'Model': '%s'%(years, makes, models)},
                callback=self.model(years, makes))

        print hxs.select('//td[@id="tdCityMpg"]/text()')
```

my basic idea with this code was to select one form field then call a formRequest and have a call back to another function that then continues on the loop till i get to the last one then i start reading the info of every car. but i keep getting a few errors... one being 
gasbuddy has no attribute 'encoding' (which I have no clue what that is about).
I'm also not sure if you can pass perimeters to a call back function.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer only covers ways of calling callbacks with additional arguments and doesn't solve problem with dynamic forms for your concrete site.

For passing additional parameters to callback you can use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from standard Python library.

Simplified example without Scrapy:

```
import functools


def func(self, response):
    print self, response

def func_with_param(self, response, param):
    print self, response, param    

def caller(callback):
    callback('self', 'response')

caller(func)
caller(functools.partial(func_with_param, param='param'))
```

So you should define `make` and `model` functions like this (`self` is always first argument):

```
def make (self, response, years):
    ...

def model (self, response, years, makes):
    ...
```

And callback parameter:

```
import functools
...

def parse(self, response):
    ...
    return FormRequest(url="http://www.gasbuddy.com/Trip_Calculator.aspx",
                       formdata={'Year': '%s'%("2011")},
                       callback=functools.partial(self.make, years='2011'))
```

---

Another option to pass arguments to callback in Scrapy is to use [`meta`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=meta#scrapy.http.Request.meta) argument for `FormRequest`

e.g.:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    return FormRequest(url="http://www.gasbuddy.com/Trip_Calculator.aspx",
                       formdata={'Year': '%s'%("2011")},
                       meta={'years':'2011'},
                       callback=self.make)

def make (self, response):
    years = response.meta['years']
    ...
```

And similiar for `models`.

Another problem in your code, `FormRequest`'s are only created and not used. You should return them (like in my `parse` example) or `yield` them in for loop:

```
for something in hxs.select(...).extract():
    yield FormRequest(...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such an in depth explanation. this is so helpful. you are my hero. :)

Comment: @AlexW.H.B. trying to do something similar, can you share how you solved this issue ? new to python, but if you share your code i might understand, as having php background.